# PHP - [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:

Tags: php, soap

After reading all the suggestions on stackoverflow, I've still had no success  in fixing this SOAP Error.

Link: http://154.0.172.64/~littleloans/test.php

```
  $vec = array(
      'Customer_AccountNo'=>239362,
      'PMonth'=>2,
      'PYear'=>2016);

    $soap_client = new SoapClient('https://secure.acpas.co.za/wsIntegrationexternalintegration.asmx?WSDL');
        $ab = $soap_client->Get_Customer_NextPayDate($vec);


    var_dump($ab);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://secure.acpas.co.za/wsIntegrationexternalintegration.asmx?WSDL' : Entity 'nbsp' not defined in /home/littleloans/public_html/test.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/littleloans/public_html/test.php(10): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://secure....') #1 {main} thrown in /home/littleloans/public_html/test.php on line 10

This is what I've got enabled in php,ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Also, file_get_contents() works fine.

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: You should really post your php code here.

Comment: Looks like the url https://secure.acpas.co.za/wsIntegrationexternalintegration.asmx?WSDL is wrong.